# Dibujar una cruz con asteriscos según las filas y columnas que se indiquen por consola en Java

Tags: java, array

Tengo el ejercicio en que me piden dibujar una cruz en función del número de filas y de columnas que se piden por consola

Hice la parte general, o sea, la sencilla, pero me falta la principal, la que dibuja la cruz

he probado varias cosas, pero me salen cosas raras al imprimir

Alguien me podría ayudar ?

código:

```
public class CruzArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        int f,c;

        System.out.print("Ingrese el número de filas: ");
        f = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese el número de columnas: ");
        c = teclado.nextInt();
       
        System.out.println();
   
        char[][] matriz = new char [f][c];
   
        int mitadFilas = matriz.length / 2;
        int mitadColumnas = matriz[0].length / 2;
   
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
                matriz [i][j] = '*';
                matriz [i][j] = ' ';
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: una cruz de que forma? `x` ó `+`

Comment: Pues lo siento, no reparé en ese detalle. Como cruz imaginé la segunda (+).

Comment: Ahh, si perdón por no indicarlo, me refería a la cruz normal +. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No especificas nada en tu pregunta, en la forma que te hayan planteado el problema, y es, que si el usuario te indica como número de filas o de columnas un número par, la cruz no te saldría regular, pues a parecería desplazada hacia la derecha.

Te propongo una solución, que añadiría una fila o una columna de más, si el usuario indica ese número par en las mismas, y se lo indicamos por medio de un mensaje de texto.

A parte, te completo el código que iría dentro de los bucles.

En mi caso me limito a validar que cuando el doble bucle encuentre la mitad de las filas o de las columnas, escriba el asterisco.

Si no es la mitad lo que encuentra en cada iteración, escriba un espacio en blanco.

Espero te sirva

```
public class CruzArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   
        //instanciamos la clase escaner
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
   
        //creamos dos variables booleanas para validar que los números introducidos por consola sean impares para hallar su mitad
        boolean numeroCorrectoA = false;
        boolean numeroCorrectoB = false;
    
        //declaramos las variables enteras para las filas y las columnas
        int f,c;

        //pedimos las filas
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de filas: ");
        //recogemos las filas en la variable f
        f = teclado.nextInt();
        //pedimos las columnas
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de columnas: ");
        //recogemos las columnas en la variable c
        c = teclado.nextInt();
       
        //comprobamos que el número de filas sea impar
        if(f % 2 != 0) {
            //si lo es, ponemos la variable a true
            numeroCorrectoA = true;
        //si no lo es
        }else {
            //le sumamos uno para convertirlo en impar
            f++;
            //ponemos las variable a true, ya que ahora es impar
            numeroCorrectoA = true;
            //informamos al usuario que a su número de filas, le añadiremos una más
            System.out.println("Para realizar un dibujo correcto, hemos incrementado una fila para poder calcular su mitad");
        }
        //comprobamos que el número de columnas sea impar
        if(c % 2 != 0) {
            //si lo es, ponemos la variable a true
            numeroCorrectoB = true;
        //si no lo es
        }else {
            c++;
            //ponemos la variable a true
            numeroCorrectoB = true;
            //informamos al usuario que a su número de columnas, le añadiremos una más
            System.out.println("Para realizar un dibujo correcto, hemos incrementado una columna para poder calcular su mitad");
        }
        //Separamos la petición de datos del resultado con dos líneas en blanco
        System.out.println("\n");
   
        //creamos un array bidimensional limitando las filas y columnas con los datos del usuario o deser pares, incrementadas en uno
        char[][] matriz = new char [f][c];
   
        //calculamos la mitad de las filas y de las columnas
        int mitadFilas = matriz.length / 2;
        int mitadColumnas = matriz[0].length / 2;
   
        //bucle que recorre las filas
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            //bucle que recorre las columnas
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
                //creas un if que evalúe si la variable de cada bucle alcanza la mitad de filas y columnas que será donde pongamos los asteriscos
                if(i == mitadFilas || j == mitadColumnas) {
                    //si coincide con esa mitad, pones el asterisco
                    matriz [i][j] = '*';
                }else {
                    //si no cincide, pones un espacio en blanco
                    matriz [i][j] = ' ';
                }
                //completas el dibujo con otro espacio en blanco, estamos trabajando con la mitad, o sea, ahy que rellenar a cada lado
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            }
            //creas una nueva línea
            System.out.println();
        }
        //finalizamos la clase escaner
        teclado.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probado y funciona perfecto. No había pensado en la posibilidad de que el número indicado de filas o columnas fuera par, y es cierto, comenté en incremento de las variables y sale el dibujo desplazado. Muchas gracias @el.trasgu

Comment: Hola @EstebanConcheso. Si la respuesta te encaja y es lo que pedías, por favor, marcha la respuesta como aceptada para cerrar la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Ahh, sí, perdón, no sabía. Marcada.

Comment: te puedes simplificar mucho código si usas el operador ternario `(condicion)?valor: otro`. iba a dar una respuesta pero se asemeja bastante a lo que tienes

Comment: Te agradecería la pusieras @Christian, desconozco como hacerlo como dices. Un saludo

Comment: @el.trasgu añadí la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

La forma que encontré de hacerlo es agregando 1 columna o fila a lo que indica el usuario, pues para hacer una cruz debe tener la misma longitud partiendo del centro y en caso el número sea par habrá un *error* en como se arma la cruz, para eso un operador ternario para simplificar el código, el resto es solo llenar la matriz dependiendo si coincide con que sea la mitad.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        int f,c;

        System.out.print("Ingrese el número de filas: ");
        f = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese el número de columnas: ");
        c = teclado.nextInt();
       
        System.out.println();
        // sumamos 1 si es par  
        f = (f%2)==0 ?f+1: f;
        c = (c%2)==0 ?c+1: c;

        char[][] matriz = new char [f][c]; //creamos la matriz
        int mitadFilas = (matriz.length / 2)+1; //obtenemos la mitad
        int mitadColumnas = (matriz[0].length / 2)+1; //obtenemos la mitad

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                if(j+1==mitadColumnas || i+1==mitadFilas){
                    matriz [i][j] = '*';
                }else{
                    matriz [i][j] = ' ';
                }
            }
            System.out.print(matriz[i]);
            System.out.print('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vaya, uno que cree ir aprendiendo poco a poco, y luego llegan respuestas como la tuya que me hacen pensar que no tengo ni idea. Tendré que estudiar los métodos que utilizas, porque ahora mismo me son totalmente desconocidos. Muchas gracias @Christian, da gusto ilustrarse con vosotros.

Comment: @el.trasgu por eso es grandioso estar en una comunidad como SO :D